# How to round to the nearest future timestamp?

Tags: r, datatable, lubridate

I am using the lubridate function round_date to round timestamps like below:

```
round_date(as.POSIXct("2015-11-26 23:51:15"),"5 mins")
```

This gives as "2015-11-26 23:50:00 +08"

But I want to round it to future 5 mins not past. Like

```
round_date(as.POSIXct("2015-11-26 23:51:15"),"5 mins")
```

should round all the timestamps from `2015-11-26 23:50:01` to `2015-11-26 23:54:59` to

```
2015-11-26 23:55:00.
```

Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(as.POSIXct("2015-11-26 23:54:49"),"5 mins")
```

rounds all  all the timestamps from `2015-11-26 23:50:01` to `2015-11-26 23:54:59` to `2015-11-26 23:55:00`.